# On a limit of a sequence of an operator images

Tags: functional-analysis

I have on L$^2(0, 1)$ a linear bounded operator that satisfies,
given an infinite sequence $\{\xi_n\}$, $\parallel \xi_{n} \parallel = 1$ for every n $\geq 1$ :

$\|T\xi_{n}\|$ is monotone decreasing sequence to 0 for $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I want to show that there exists z not null such that Tz = 0, z being the weak limit of a subsequence $\xi_{n_k}$.

How I want to prove: the subsequence exists because the original sequence is bounded. Its limit z, is not null because should be in a neighborhood of the sequence's terms.
Now, T$\xi_{n_k} \rightharpoonup $ Tz and, we have the convergence in norm of the same sequence, T$\xi_{n_k}$.
Thus, Tz = 0. Is it correct ?
Thanks

Comment: weak convergence does *not* imply convergence of norms. You only have weak lower semicontinuity

Comment: Sorry, if I didn't explain correctly: I have the convergence in norm, $\|T\xi_{n}\| \rightarrow 0$, where the sequence $\xi_{n} $  is on the unit sphere ($\parallel \xi_{n} \parallel = 1$ for every n $\geq 1$).  I want to show that the limit of the norms  $\|T\xi_{n}\|$ is Tz = 0, where z is a not null element using the existence of a subsequence of $ \xi_{n} $ weak convergent to an element not null, z.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. The problem is that the weak limit $z$ might be zero. Here is an example:
$$
(T\xi)(x) = x\xi(x),
$$
$\xi_n(x) = \sqrt n \chi_{(0,1/n)}(x)$. Then $\|\xi_n\|_{L^2(0,1)}=1$, $\xi_n$ converges to zero weakly and pointwise a.e., and
$\|T\xi_n\|_{L^2(0,1)}=\frac1{n\sqrt 3}$, but $T$ is injective.